# How to delete user created by websecurity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I use WebSecurity to create my user's accounts.

```
var confirmationToken = WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.Username, model.Password, 
                    new { Email = model.Email,
                        Lastname = model.Lastname,
                        Firstname = model.Firstname,
                        Birthday = model.Birthday,
                        Job = model.Job,
                        City = model.City,
                        Gender = model.Gender,
                        PictureFilename = "anonyme.png"
                }, true);
```

But how can i delete a user ?

Comment: The following link may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13391166/how-to-delete-a-simplemembership-user In the above link they specified how to delete an user

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
((SimpleMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider).DeleteAccount(userName); // deletes record from webpages_Membership table
((SimpleMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider).DeleteUser(userName, true); // deletes record from UserProfile table
```

Comment: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "fk_UserId". The conflict occurred in database "AspNetDB", table "dbo.webpages_UsersInRoles", column 'UserId'.

Comment: check if user is having roles or not something like this 

`if (WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.UserExists(username))
    {
     var userRoles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(username);
     
     if (userRoles.Count() > 0) Roles.RemoveUserFromRoles(username, userRoles);
     ((SimpleMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider).DeleteAccount(username); // deletes record from webpages_Membership table
     ((SimpleMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider).DeleteUser(username, true);
    }`