# is it possible to delete row from default table AspNetUsers ? if yes please explain

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

is it possible to delete row from default table AspNetUsers ? if  yes please explain.

i able to delete record which has Fk of AspNetUsers.

public ActionResult Delete(STUDENT st)
        {
                var studentuser = st.user;
                st.user = null;
                db.Entry(st).State = EntityState.Deleted;
                db.SaveChanges();// delete from db successfully 
 
                var userid = User.Identity.GetUserId();
                var user = _userManager.FindById(userid);
                _userManager.DeleteAsync(user);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
        }

Answer (score 3):

This is a code snippet I've used previously to delete a user

```
// Find the user
var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
var logins = user.Logins;

// Delete every login, if he has
foreach (var login in logins.ToList())
{
  await _userManager.RemoveLoginAsync(login.UserId, new UserLoginInfo(login.LoginProvider, login.ProviderKey));
}

// Delete every role, if he has
var rolesForUser = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(id);
if (rolesForUser.Count() > 0)
{
    foreach (var item in rolesForUser.ToList())
    {
       // item should be the name of the role
       var result = await _userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(user.Id, item);
    }
}

// Delete the user itself
_await _userManager.DeleteAsync(user);
```

Comment: :( i am using my custom controller

Comment: @VishalPatidar You're going to have to be more specific about your problem then. Jelle offered a solution for what you were asking for.

Comment: i update my problem ... sorry i m beginner that's why unable to explaining my problem also

Comment: can u please explain what is "id"  here in code ...  i get id by User.Identity.GetUserId(); but it is not working

Comment: The id is the user id, it is called from the view @html.actionlink("Delete", new { id = user.id}).. Something like this...

Answer (score 2):

Yeh it does. 
But at first you have to remove all existing roles from the user before deleting it.

The example: `Roles.RemoveUserFromRoles("userName",Roles.GetRolesForUser("userName"));`

There is a link to similar question:[how-to-delete-a-simplemembership-user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13391166/how-to-delete-a-simplemembership-user)